# How to call a method inside a class method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a question.

This is my class:

```
class Provider
  include HTTParty
  CONFIG = Rails.configuration.mediaset[Rails.env]

  def self.category
    response = HTTParty.get(CONFIG['category_url'])
    category_hash = JSON.parse response.body
    if category_hash['resultCode'] == 'OK' 
      return convert_categories(category_hash)
    end
  end

  def convert_categories(cat_hash)
    h = cat_hash.find_all_values_for('categoryList')
    category_array = h.map { |c| c.except!('categoryList') }
  end
end
```

When I try to call 'Provider.category' the result is:

```
undefined method `convert_categories' for Provider:Class
```

How can I add a function to process my hash?

Comment: You could write, `return new.convert_categories(category_hash)`. What do you want `Provider::category` to return if `category_hash['resultCode'] != 'OK'`?

Comment: Why not make `convert_categories` a class method as well? It doesn't use any instance state, so it's got no dependencies in that regard. That method is quite confused in terms of function. Why do you call `map` and then discard the result? You probably want `each` instead.

Comment: I know the difference between instance method and class method, but I cannot understand how can I create a simple function to call inside my class method to increase the readability of the code.

Comment: There is no difference between a `class_function` and a "simple function". Ruby is Oriented Object, so every function you define has to belong to something.

Answer (score 4):

As has been suggested, just make your "simple function" a class method as well...

```
  def self.convert_categories(cat_hash)
    h = cat_hash.find_all_values_for('categoryList')
    h.map { |c| c.except!('categoryList') }
    return h
  end
```

do that, and the code will work.

Without the `self.` the method is an instance method and can only be called on an object of the Provider class.

Although admittedly the `h.map...` line is pointless. The result isn't saved anywhere, you're still returning the original `h` object.